# Increase rate limit of Spotify API

Tags: spotify

I have a lot of users on my web app and I reach the limit of Spotify API request (error 429).

```
stdClass Object
(
   [error] => stdClass Object
       (
           [status] => 429
           [message] => API rate limit exceeded
       )

)
```

Where can I ask for an increase rate limit of the API Spotify?

Comment: Are you already using Authorization as per https://developer.spotify.com/web-api/authorization-guide/ ?

Comment: I use an access_token for doing my requests yes.

Comment: As this question isn't actually programming related it is off topic for this site.  You would probably have to ask this question on the Spotify forum https://community.spotify.com/

Comment: That's good, i found it ! I will post on it, thanks !